# Profinet Configuration

Tags: communication, ethernet, plc

I'm trying to communicate a PC with SIEMENS s7 1200 cpu 1214 dc/dc/dc via PROFINET. I have not found any source yet. This [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519573/mapping-of-real-time-process-data-in-profinet?rq=1) seems useful but I do not know how to create a GSD file. It is written in some web sites that GSD files are provided by manufacturer of PLC. However, according to SIEMENS support forum, there is no file like this. How can I create a GSD file and use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you ask this on the Siemens Automation forum. You'll have a lot more people familiar with the topic. It's marginally off-topic on this site anyway.

Comment: IIRC - If you are doing this from scratch (not using a SCADA package) you will have to create your own GSD file, have you searched for how to do that? For instance [Link](https://rt-labs.com/docs/p-net/creating_gsdml_files.html#:~:text=%20Creating%20GSD%20%28GSDML%29%20files%20%C2%B6%20%201,name%20format%20is%20specified%20in%20section...%20More%20)